# unable to create a label in gmail api using javascript

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

Sorry for being Amateur at this but please help,I am trying to create new label name news1 and this is code i have done.

This is the function call which i have used.

```
createLabel();
```

My function

```
 function createLabel() {
var newLabelName="news1";
 var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.create({

'userId' : 'me',
'labels' : {
"labelListVisibility"   : "labelShow",
"messageListVisibility" : "show",
"name" : newLabelName,
"id" : "news"
}
});
request.execute();
}
```

Comment: Please show us the error you get from the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your function like this only, it can't works.
You have to authenticate yourself first with a client id provided by Google and permissions scopes you need for your code.

Ressources :

Quickstart with gmail js (authentification) : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js
Creation label doc : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the Label ID. It will be provided to you in the response if the Label is successfully created.